# Running Django on a Linux Server using Apache with HTTPS

Tags: django, linux, apache, https

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and nothing I've found has really been helping.

I've got a remote Linux server running with Apache installed, and right now everything going to the server is redirected to HTTPS through Apache. This all works fine and I can access the files I need to normally, but now I'd like to also add in a Django site to my server under a new "subdomain". (For example I'd like to still be able to access non-Django files as usual 'https://www.thesite.com/path/to/file.php' and also be able to access the Django site like 'https://www.thesite.com/djangosite/some/site/page')

Could someone please give me some direction as to how I'd be able to do this? I can supply more information if it's needed.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: The Django server seems to dislike connecting via HTTPS and I'm getting an error that it can only support HTTP, but I need it because I want the site to be secure, and currently Apache is redirecting all HTTP requests to HTTPS, so do I need some other method of making it work?

Comment: You can create another host entry for that route & then access the site. Search on google. you might be able to find the configuration easily

Comment: You have to decide which app server will serve your WSGI Django application. You can use `mod_wsgi`, `uwsgi` or  `gunicorn`. The first two are described on the official [Django documentation site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). If you look there you'll also see how to use `WSGIScriptAlias` to serve Django under a specific path (rather than `/`)

Comment: I installed mod_wsgi and was trying to use WSGIScriptAlias but I wasn't sure what file it was meant to go into. Also when I tried to access any Django page i got an error that I couldn't use HTTPS and only HTTP was supported and I wasn't sure if I needed something else to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Check out SNI and also potentially wild card certificates

Comment: The issue isn't so much that I need two certificates, I'm fine with both sections requiring the HTTPS (preferred in fact), I'd more like to know how to set up Django so it works with the HTTPS and it's under a separate URL section.